# Autogenerate Serial Number for DataBound DataGridView gives StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, stack-overflow, autogeneratecolumn

I am generating serial number for a column in Datagridview using the following code it gives me error...,

```
 private void dgvQttnfrm_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (dgvQttnfrm.RowCount != 0)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < dgvQttnfrm.RowCount; i++)
               {
                   dgvQttnfrm.Rows[i].Cells["Slno"].Value = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

please suggest me there is any event for this to auto generate serial number

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: It properly has to do with the event you handle. If possible, try setting the serialnumber *before* adding to the dataGridView

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to generate serial no automatically

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slno">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: it is tagged as winfroms not asp.net

Comment: `</asp>`? OP is in WinForms